# Creating services manually with Icinga2 API not working

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

I am new on Icinga2, using 2.4.0 version and I am trying to execute some API calls but I have found a problem when I have tried to create a service manually.

This is the command that I execute to create a service called api_dummy_service_1 for api_dummy_host_1 host:

```
curl -u $ICINGA2_API_USER:$ICINGA2_API_PASSWORD  \
     -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT \
     -k "https://$ICINGA2_HOST:$ICINGA2_API_PORT/v1/objects/services/api_dummy_host_1!api_dummy_service_1" \
     -d '{ "templates": [ "generic-service" ], "attrs": { "display_name": "api_dummy_service_1", "check_command" : "dns", "vars.dns_lookup": "google-public-dns-a.google.com.", "vars.dns_expected_answer": "8.8.8.8", "host_name": "api_dummy_host_1" } }' | python -m json.tool
```

When I execute it, the following error message appears:

```
-bash: !api_dummy_service_1: event not found
```

I have examinated Icinga logs, I have activated debug mode on Icinga also and tried to search information related to this in internet with no results.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed! After doing more test in detail we have detected that the problem was related to the URL that we use to connect with icinga2 API, the ! character must be escaped.

I have changed ! to %21 and the command works